# What's the advantage of view blocks?

Tags: 7, views, blocks

Instead of creating a block for each view, I simply display the master views in the panels on my website. As that works perfectly until now, I'm wondering why one should create a view block. Do they have any advantages over master views? Is my way of acting risky in a sense?

Comment: There are some advantages in some situations to use content pane displays if you are using Panels. Getting proper contex is one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of methods to control the layout of your site, and to arrange different elements into a page. Panels is one method. If you don't use Panels, the system of regions and blocks is probably your primary tool. (BTW, you can also mix panels and blocks.)

Personally I'm not a panels user, but I guess it's very possible that you will never need block views if you use Panels.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder how you embed the View in your site.
(I'm aware of views_embed_view() or any other PHP method. We good people don't even enable the PHP module do we?)

1. Block caching. Views exposed the Views to the blocks system, so they can cached, altered, and just about anything regarding blocks can be done.
2. If you want to have multiple blocks/displays out of the same View, you do have to create blocks. More views = more headache.

Comment: As I'm working with panels, I can add views to my website directly without creating a block first. I've added that to my question.

Comment: Ah, that's important info here!